# Etiqueta Select cambio su estilo cuando es MacBook

Tags: html, css, sass

Saludos!!
Yo tengo una etiqueta html llamada `<select>` con la clase de bootstrap `form-control` esta clase me agrega unos estilos los cuales son estos:

```
.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 34px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.428571429;
    color: #555555;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
    transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
}
```

como podemos ver tiene un `border-radius: 0;`, mi problema es que cuando abro la pagina en MacBook la etiqueta `<select>` se visualiza como si tuviera un `border-radius`. Agrego una imagen para ver el error.

[image: Error]

Comment: lo abres con Macbook, pero .. lo abres con Safari imagino, no ?

Comment: @lois6b no en Chrome

Comment: [Prueba con esta configuracion](https://jsfiddle.net/wvyoabbL/)

Comment: @LuisFernando Por que no lo pones como respuesta? ^^

Comment: Porque no se si eso es lo que busca, porque para mi gusto ese select se ve mas bonito en MacBook :)

Comment: @LuisFernando voy a probar tu respuesta :)

Answer (score 1):

Te recomendaría restablecer las configuraciones por defecto de la etiqueta con esto no deberías tener problemas, ¡¡suerte!!

```
select {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cada navegador implementa de una forma los input. Lo mejor para solucionar este problema es, quitar la apariencia como comenta Muriano y después ayudándote de ::before y ::after realizar el diseño que más te guste.